# Suma de matrices en Java

Tags: java, matrices

Necesito sumar las filas para que me de el total de equipos empacados por día, y las columnas para el total de equipos empacados por cada operador.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class bidimensionales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String entrada, entradan, entradam;
        System.out.println("EQUIPOS EMPACADOS");
        int i, j, n, m;
        int [][]A;
        int totaln, totalm;
        entradan = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese cantidad de dias a evaluar: ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(entradan);
        entradam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese numero de operadores: ");
        m = Integer.parseInt(entradam);
        A = new int [n][m];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++) {
                entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Equipos empacados en el: \n Dia["+(i+1)+"] por Operador["+(j+1)+"] = ");
                A[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(entrada);
            }
        }
        String letrero = "Dia, filas["+n+"]\nOperador, columnas["+m+"]\n";
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for (j=0;j<m;j++) { 
                letrero = letrero + A[i][j] + " ";
            }
            letrero = letrero + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letrero);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            totaln=0;
            letrero = letrero + A[i] + " ";
            totaln = totaln + A[i];
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,letrero);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total de equipos empacados por dia: "+ totaln);
    }
}
```

Intenté con un contador también:

```
for(int contador=0;contador<A.length;contador++) {
    totaln=0;
    totaln += A[i][contador];
    System.out.println(A[i][contador] + "-->" +totaln);
}
```

En este último me corre, pero no me hace la suma, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho ya que apenas estoy aprendiendo y familiarizándome con matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Por cada iteración en el bucle for estas asignando a 0 de nuevo la variable con la que estas sumamdo (totaln), por eso no te esta sumando, saludos

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [answer]. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu respuesta te invito a hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo soy mas partidario de los List antes que de los arrays. Te pongo el contador, guardando los resultados en listas:

- Equipos empacados por día (filas) --> empacDias
- Equipos empacados por operador (columnas) --> empacOper

Vayamos al código, sabiendo que las variables `n` y `m` contienen el tamaño máximo de las dimensiones.

```
//Inicializamos las listas a todo ceros
List<Integer> empacDias = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(n, 0));
List<Integer> empacOper = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(m, 0));
for(final int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(final int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        empacDias.set(j,empacDias.get(j)+A[i][j]); //Filas
        empacOper.set(i,empacOper.get(i)+A[i][j]); //Columnas
    }   
}
```

Ahora solo tienes que recorrer cada lista para ver los resultados